# Loop through unknown object

Tags: c#

The problem I'm facing is looping through an `object`.

Part of my Resource class looks like this:

```
public List<PhoneCodeInfo> PhoneCodes { get; set; }
public List<CountryInfo> Countries { get; set; }
public List<BrandDetail> Brands { get; set; }
public List<FileTypeDetail> FileTypes { get; set; }
public object Enums { get; set; } // <- is the problem
```

I can easy loop through all except `Enums` because "I" dont know what it looks like.

[image]

I'm looping through `PhoneCodes` like:

```
foreach (var phoneCode in value.PhoneCodes)
{
    current += GetHashString(phoneCode.Code);
}
```

but how can I loop the `Enums` / get the children of it.

I've tried converting the `Enums` into a Json object, but no luck

Comment: "I've tried"..."no luck". What went wrong exactly? Is the Enums a string in your example? In that case it appears that it would be parseable as JSON, and then you could loop over the parsed data (if you used JSON.NET you could get a JArray or a dynamic to loop over). But it's always going to be tricky to loop over something if the data structure is unpredictable, because you need to know at least something, like field names, that you want to look for. Or maybe you'd be better using Generics, or forcing it to supply something IEnumerable. It's not clear _how_ unpredictable your data will be

Comment: its type is `object` and that's not iterable.

Comment: or as @ADyson said, you should parse the JSON to objects and then try to iterate

Comment: Could you please show your json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
        public enum Test
        {
            One,
            Two,
            Three,
            Four
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string[] names = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Test)).ToArray();
            foreach (var name in names)
            {
                int value = (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(Test),name);
            }
        }
```